# fastest non volatile memory type available for High Performance Computing/ Cloud computing?

Tags: hard-drive, memory, ssd, distributed-computing, cloud-computing

I am working on parallel computing and distributed programs and noticed that file i/o is quite a bottleneck. It seems quite clear this particular aspect is major issue in many high performance solutions.

So I was just curious what would be the fastest class of non volatile memory available ? No specific brands but types ... commercial and/or experimental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my work in HPC, network storage is a common bottle neck.

**Theoretical fastest storage**

The absolute fastest hard drives, are actually RAM disks. It is possible to [achieve 5GBs](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMnwMopeXV4) using consumer hardware. Though you will be limited to a few dozen gigs of storage at most.

**Actual fastest storage**

The fastest devices right now are NAND storage devices. You don't want to mention brands, but I am going to mention one anyway. 
Check out the [Fusion-io ioDrive](http://www.storagereview.com/fusionio_iodrive2_mlc_application_accelerator_review_12tb). NAND storage devices can reach 2GBs.

**High Performance Computing**

Ram disks, and NAND disk are great for being fast, but they have very limited capacity for HPC. A much more common solution is to use a premade SAN running on SSD

[Panasis](http://www.panasas.com)

[Cray](http://www.cray.com/Products/Products.aspx)

[X-IO Tech](http://xiostorage.com)

I know you aren't looking for brands, but if you look at what all the experts in HPC are using, you can see the different technologies.